# Firefox & OpenOffice don't use Indicator Applet Application Menu

Tags: unity, firefox, appmenu, openoffice.org

At present, it seems neither Firefox nor Open Office seem to be using the Indicator Applet Application Menu. Is there a work around/fix committed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's "known issue" -- support for OOo and XUL-based application (Firefox, Thunderbird...) is planned but not implemented yet and I think there's no workaround yet.

Related bugs:

- Firefox: https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-appmenu/+bug/637827
- OpenOffice: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-appmenu/+bug/664731

Comment: Firefox (and by extension Thunderbird) should work for 11.04, based on excellent progress made by Chris Coulson in December.